# Flex 1 not working properly in react-native

Tags: react-native

For parent View I have set flex 1 and for child view, I have given Flex 1 and Flex 4 respectively. But the first child view is taking all the spaces.

Plz refer the below screenshot

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.appContainer}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Add your goal' />
        <Button title='Add me' />
      </View >
      <View styles={styles.goalContainer}>
        <Text>List of goals...</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

// Styles

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 16
  }
  ,
  inputContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 24,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#cccccc'
  },
  textInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#cccccc',
    width: '70%',
    marginRight: 8,
    padding: 8
  },
  goalContainer: {
    flex: 4
  }}) //Forgot to add curly bracket and closing bracket
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct style spelling in View.

```js
<View style={styles.goalContainer}>
   <Text>List of goals...</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with below code

```
import React from 'react'
import {View,StyleSheet,Text,TextInput,Button} from 'react-native'
export default function App() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.appContainer}>
   <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
   <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Add your goal' />
        <Button title='Add me' />
   </View>

   <View style={styles.goalContainer}>
    <Text>List of goals...</Text>
   </View>
   </View>
  );
}

// Styles

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    backgroundColor: null,
  }
  ,
  inputContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 24,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#cccccc',
    backgroundColor:null
  },
  textInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#cccccc',
    width: '70%',
    marginRight: 8,
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor:null
  },
  goalContainer: {
    flex: 4,
    backgroundColor: null
  }
})
```